# Why is a percent value for startOffset in textPath not being responsive/consistent in different window sizes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using a percentage value for startOffset in textPath. The path is a normal curve. Depending on my window size, my text shows up in a different percentile on the normal distribution. I'm confused,because percentage values are typically responsive. How can I get the text to consistently start from the x percentile?

The textPath I am using is a normal curve made from plotting data from a normal sample and using this to draw the curve

```
let curve = d3.line().curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x( (d) => scale_x(d[0]) )
    .y( (d) => scale_y(d[1]) );
```

When I set the text element, it successfully curves to the path. However, depending on my window size when I call the function, the startOffset puts the text at a different part of the curve.

```
d3.select("#svg1").select("#normal_g").append('text')
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("x", scale_x(mu))
    .attr("y",(d,i)=>dim.y+dim.height *.65)
 d3.select("#svg1").select("#normal_g").select('text')
    .append("textPath").text("Normal Distribution")
    .attr("href", "#normal") // #normal is a normal curve
    .attr("startOffset" , "50%") //<---This is the attribute that I'm confused by
```

Comment: Can you link to a working example?

Comment: the working example is really long and it's all sort of chained on top of each other. Would a picture help? or I could copy/paste the path maybe? Am i understanding startOffset correctly?